# C1083 : Permission denied on .sbr files

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I am using Visual Studio 2005 (with SP1) and I am getting weird errors concerning .sbr files. These files, as I read on MSDN, are intermediate files for BSCMAKE to generate a .bsc file.

The errors I get are, for example (on different builds) :

```
11>string.cpp : fatal error C1083: Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier généré(e) par le compilateur : '.\debug\String.sbr' : Permission denied
```

```
58>type.cpp : fatal error C1083: Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier généré(e) par le compilateur : '.\Debug/Type.sbr' : Permission denied
```

*Translation : cannot open compiler intermediate file*

It seems to be consistent (I have at least 5 or 6 examples like this) with a .cpp file being compiled twice in the same project, respectively :

```
11>String.cpp
*some warnings, 2 lines*
11>String.cpp
```

```
58>Type.cpp
*some warnings and other files compiled, a lot of lines*
58>Type.cpp
```

I already checked the .vcproj files for duplicate entries and it does not seem to be the problem.

I would appreciate any help regarding this issue. Deactivating the build of .bsc files seems to be a workaround but maybe someone has better information than this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your sbr file properties to see are the files read only.

Comment: The files are created by BSCMAKE without any problem and they are not read only. My guess is that they are opened by an instance of the compiler which tries to open it again but can't.

It seems to be a problem of concurrent builds with either cl or bscmake.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a conflict between multiple projects in your solution.  A detailed set of possible fixes are listed in the answer to [VC2008 compiler errors opening sbr files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1182583/222481).